# Switching between UIViewControllers with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

Right I have looked at a few SO questions on the subject and I am finding it difficult to come up with the correct solution here.

**Requirements**

I have a UITabBar based application. One of the tabs has a `UINavigation` controller with `UISegmentedControl` at the top allowing the user to switch between three different views. 
Each view will have a UITableView which will allow the user to navigate to another view. These views should be pushed onto to the navigation controller.

**Problem**

Now all the SO questions and Answers on the subject show how to switch between views. However I need the view I switch to, to allow pushing of another view onto the navigation stack. I am not sure this is even possible. I thought about UIViewController containment - however that would show a view being pushed onto the stack in a smaller window that the screen's bounds. Not what I am looking for.

Any ideas how I can solve this with storyboards and UIViewControllers?

**UPDATE**

Here is what I am trying to do: In the screenshot the container area is where I need to load other view controllers into. The UISegment control cannot go into the navigation bar as that space is used for something else. So that's why I think UIViewController containment might be better here?

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to do a pushViewController onto your `UINavigationController` to create the navigation stack when you click on one of the UISegmentedControl buttons. Does that not work?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The push part is not where I am stuck. See the update in my question. :) I am sure push will work though once I get there.

Comment: Oh interesting - so you want a navigation stack within that grey area, similar to the functionality of a UIWebView?

Comment: @LyricalPanda Not quite. The grey area needs to show three different UIVIewControllers. (UISegmented control has two segments - just for demo purposes) - selecting either of those segments will swop out the view in the grey area to a different view controller. (Thats the first bit I am stuck on) the second bit I was concerned about was pushing a new view controller onto the stack when user taps on a UItableView cell in the grey area. I want the new view controller to be full screen and not resized (But I am trying to tackle my first problem for now ) - I hope this clears it up?

Comment: Yup! Sorry it took me so long to understand the problem. Is your logic for each of the views drastically different? Even though you're looking for a solution using UIViewControllers, I know this could be solved by creating custom UIViews that are hidden by default and showing them when you select a button. This could be one approach to take if you don't have completely separate logic for each one.

Comment: No problem, sorry for not being clear. I had considered that approach. The logic for each VC will be a little different. I could have put everything into a single VC. And use xibs. However this will be one bloated VC class as there is a lot of code. I really wanted to break it up for easier maintainability / debugging / etc. I am not sure how else to approach this issue. My app uses this UI design a lot so I want to find a good solution now and reuse it - so looking for scalability - which is why I looked to a container view. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LyricalPanda Can you mark your last comment as an answer. I have decided to take the approach as the simplest way forward and will just make the code as neat as possible as well as readable and separated nicely. Seems like the best solution here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So even though this isn't using separate `TableViewControllers`, you can use different custom `UIViews` that are hidden by default and become visible when you select it's corresponding button. This will unfortunately make it so you have all three view's logic in the same VC.

To get around this, you can try setting up some delegates and mimicking the `TableViewController` logic separation by sending out the `didSelectTableAtIndexPath`, `UIGesture` touches, etc into classes outside the `ViewController` to help keep your code cleaner.

Comment: Since most of the logic for all three views are just simple table views the code won't be too messy. Thanks for the great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

User `UITabBarController` and hide the tab bar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     self.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

Binding the segment control with method `valueChanged`

```
- (void)valueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)seg
{
    if ([seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0]) {
        self.selectedIndex = 0;
    } else if ([seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 1] {
        self.selectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

I achieve this by this way, I hope this will help.

Comment: This isn't what I need. The UITabBar must stay visible. Thanks for the help though.